# how can get album art of song from url

Tags: java, android, mediametadataretriever

want get album art of song from url and this is my try so far :

```
SongPath = "www.asd.com/music.mp3";
        android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    try{
                mmr.setDataSource(SongPath);
        }catch(Exception e){}
                byte [] data = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();

                if(data != null)
                {
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
                else
                {
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.jak);
                }
```

but when run this code get this : `call to get embedded picture failed`
so i research about this and some people fix that with change this part
`mmr.setDataSource(SongPath);`

to this

`mmr.setDataSource(SongPath,new HashMap<String, String>());`
i do that but when run app image view show nothing and get this : `SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null`

**Note :**
the only way i could do that use `FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever` library (its like `MediaMetadataRetriever`)  and worked but problem is library seems slow .. its mean 4,5sec time need to fetch pic and when add this library the apk file from 1.8mb become to 24mb! and this is so huge!

so any one in the world know how can do that with good way ? if any one can please help

Comment: where is the url , post the whole stuff

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris when you don't have enough knowledge about this don't come here and give negative vote to my question  . my question and description is clear but seems your so low and cant understand that :)

Comment: What do you mean by url? is it local path(i.e. from sdcard) or from Web?

Comment: @MdFazlaRabbiOpu web . i will change my question

Comment: @user7415865, you are the ne who is low , it's supposed to URI not URL , revise that

Answer (score 0):

You can use Glide in a similar way you would use it for a `File`: [bumptech/glide#699](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/699) if you can figure out how to do it remotely. The problem is that you still need to download the whole .mp3 file, which takes that 4-5 seconds I guess. I'm not exactly sure about the .mp3 format, but I think the album art may be at the end of the file. For this reason this approach is not suggested (similar to [how it's a bad idea to load video thumbs from http](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/862)). If you want to go this way anyway, then slap a `.diskCacheStrategy(SOURCE)` on the load to save the file first, and then write a custom decoder to use

The best approach is to have the album art served from a separate file if you host the mp3; or use a public service to retrieve it. See any album art downloader program for possible services.

One thing's for sure: without a protocol, nothing will work, prefix your `www.` with `http://` or `https://` as necessary.